# Fortigate 30D IPSEC VPN could not locate phase1 configuration

Tags: vpn, ipsec, fortigate

Hello network engineers,

I have an IPSEC VPN tunnel between two offices, the HQ is a fortigate 200B(os:v5.0,build0292 (GA Patch 9)) and the branch is fortigate 30D(os:5.2.3).

Both are now on static IPs. The branch side has an PPPoE though. `auto-reconnect is also enabled on the branch side`.

The issue we're facing since day 1 is the tunnel works fine for the day but the next morning is down and does not come up on its own at all, until some minor change is made to the phase1 configuration on the branch side.

I have a case locked with the fortigate TAC since then, it's over 2 months of submitting logs to them and no solution has been provided at all. Submitting logs to them is now a daily thing.

Running debugging during the time of the issue on the branch 30D the initial out put is `2015-08-24 21:44:34 ike 0:mandhana: could not locate phase1 configuration`.

I could find only this [one similar case](https://forum.fortinet.com/tm.aspx?m=117799) on their forums, my branch side is already on 5.2.3 so the solution of updating to 5.2 which worked there won't work for me.

Really appreciate any help towards what could be causing this.

***UPDATE 4th NOV 2015:***

The wan interface has an static IP address but its through PPPoE, so i guess there's some sort of ip address renewal still happening even though the ip address which the wan interface gets is still the same and is static.

When the ip is renewed the tunnel goes down and doesn't come up on its own for some reason.

The TAC has now declared this as a bug and tells me to wait till FortiOS 5.4.0 is released.

I am of the opinion though that this is something to do with hardware itself. If this was a bug we would have more of such cases here and elsewhere but i couldn't find any.

Here's the fortinet TAC's logging info:

```
Hi,
```

`
    -Here is what the issue started occurring today morning.
    2015-09-08 18:29:41 is PST time(your device has PST time zone), not IST time zone. So actually issue started exactly at 7:30AM today IST time.
    ---/---
    2015-09-08 18:29:41 ike 0: IP 59.x.x.x (59) is down ----<<<< probably the pppoe interface went down as the 'IP is down' in the debug logs.
    2015-09-08 18:29:41 ike 0:mandhana: deleting
    2015-09-08 18:29:41 ike 0:mandhana: flushing
    2015-09-08 18:29:41 ike 0:mandhana:79: send IPsec SA delete, spi c21221f8 ---<<<<

```
-The below debug logs confirms that default route was no longer available in FGT as per 'len=92: error 101:Network is unreachable'
-So it's highly possible that default route was removed from FGT routing table.
---/---
2015-09-08 18:29:41 ike 0:mandhana:79: could not send IKE Packet(ISAKMP SA DELETE-NOTIFY):59.x.y.z:500->14.x.z.c:500, len=92: error 101:Network is unreachable
---/---

Above continues till next 1 min.

-Next min, we see the following error

2015-09-08 18:30:16 ike 0:mandhana: could not locate phase1 configuration.
```

`
    I suspect, there is an issue with pppoe related -(routes, ip address, policy) when this issue occurs. I will login to fortigate tomorrow at 9:00 am, and figure it out that. Please don't make any changes.

The other option(i think its best) I advised you earlier is that configure the modem in L3 mode, do the nat port forwarding to Fortigate using the public IP. doing this way, avoids the pppoe config in fortigate.

You have port forward (https, http, VPN traffic) from modem to FGT.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you happen to use the internal ports as 'switch'? Could you try to split it up into individual ports and retest? I know it's some work but from the forum post it looks like there is a bug with the 30D hardware which conflicts with IPsec/IKE.

Comment: You could even try to use v5.2.4 _although_ there are known issues. Do not use for production environment at the moment. In your case it might be worth a try.

Comment: well i have already put 5.2.4 on some other devices for my clients. The internal ports are in interface mode since day one. Looking at the way fortigate support is handling this issue, i am also beginning to think it's the h/w, it'll just be a while before they simply accept it I guess now.

Comment: An address assigned by PPPoE is _not_ a static address. I could believe that there is PPPoE bug. Using the modem to do the PPPoE and NAT would allow you to assign a true static address.

Comment: @RonMaupin the address is static — yes there's some sort of renewal still happening but that address doesn't change, we got a fixed ip address just to solve this issue. Is this static ip assigned by pppoe very uncommon?

Comment: A static address is one which you specifically configure in the device, not one where the device receives it from another device. The address may not change, but it is not a static address. If the address will not change, you can try to configure it as a static address.

Comment: @RonMaupin well that is not allowed by the ISP. For now the TAC has confirmed this as a bug in 3 fortiOS versions 5.2.2, 2.3, 2.4. Will configuring the internet on another router and then port forwarding VPN ports to the fortigate solve this?

Comment: If you can assign a static address then it sounds like you could get around the bug. You could also try to downgrade the code to one where the bug doesn't exist.

Comment: @RonMaupin no the IP address setup will be as it is now through PPPoE but the plan is to set it up on another router and port forward IPsec VPN ports to the fortigate's ip.

Comment: Right, but if the other router does the PPPoE, you can set a static address on the FortiGate. If not, you need to realize this bug will prevent you from doing what you want, and you will need a code version without the bug (older or newer), or you need a different device that can do what you want, or a different ISP that will give you a static address which you can use. You need to hound FortiGate TAC, or just give up on FortiGate. We can't fix your software bug.

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this problem? I am having this same exact issue. After a power loss the VPN does not come back up. It also seems to occur even without a power loss occassionally. I'm suspecting the PPPOE is redialing intermittently causing it to renew it's ip (even though it's static). I have tried firmware versions 5.2.5, 5.2.6 and now 5.2.7. I see that 5.4.0 was recently released, but have not tried it yet. I have a ticket open with Fortinet Support for weeks now without any real answers. Any insight anyone can provide on this issue would be much appreciated. Thanks!
Ryan

Comment: @RyanW I added a cheap router in between to the PPPoE and forwarded IPsec ports to the fortigate, I think UDP 4500 and 500 and tcp 22, 443, just confirm that. Other then that TAC had assured me that this is a bug and was to be fixed in 5.4.0 so you can try that route as well. Let me know.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I upgraded to 5.4.0 and it fixed the issue.  Prior to upgrading I could reproduce the issue by rebooting the PPPoE router and the VPN would not come back up with debug showing the error "could not locate phase1 configuration".  This is no longer an issue after upgrading.  The VPN auto reconnects after a reboot.  Time will tell, but I suspect that future power outages will no longer require human intervention to re-establish the VPN tunnel.